# How to close currently opened tab in browser after ajax call is success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Below is my ajax call,Once the ajax call is success I want to close the current tab from browser.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data: null,
    url: '@Url.Action("SessionKill", "Authentication")',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (response) {
        if (response != null && response.success) {
            window.location = window.close();//from here,I want to close the tab.
        }
    },
    error: function (response) {
    }
});
```

Comment: How have you cnfirmed that your `success:` function is being called?

Comment: Does `window.close()` work ok without the `.ajax` call?  If so, that's not where the problem lies.  Add an alert to both `success:` and `error:` - maybe you're getting an error, but ignoring it?

Comment: there is no error,window.close() can only close windows opened with window.open();

Comment: success is calling.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo. Try this:

```
element.close();
```

in place of:

```
window.location = window.close();
```

> window.close can only close windows opened with window.open so you can't close the current tab in javascript. You can open a new window, store it in a variable, and then close it. – [Shaun Parsons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2098693/shaun-parsons)

for opening a window:

```js
var wind;

function openWindow() {
  wind = window.open("https://www.google.com/", "wind", "width=1000,height=700");
}

function closeWindow() {
  wind.close();
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="openWindow()" value='Open'/>
<input type="button" onclick="closeWindow()" value='Close'/>
```

**Update**

This snippet is blocked on stack overflow and hence won't execute here.

**[Why is window.open() blocked?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337916/why-is-window-open-blocked)**

Comment: I tried that also,But its not working thats why I posted this question.

Comment: While not needed, this has no impact on closing the window

Comment: `window.close` can only close windows opened with `window.open` so you can't close the current tab in javascript. You can open a new window, store it in a variable, and then close it.

Comment: looks better now @ShaunParsons

Comment: What do you mean by `element` here @ShaunParsons?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
if (response != null && response.success) {
    window.open('', '_self', ''); 
    window.close();
}
```

Comment: It will reopen the same tab.Actually I don't need that tab,I just want to close the tab.

Answer (score 0):

you cant close a window/tab that you didnt open with javascript.

if you create a window with window.open() you can close it with window.close() otherwise you cant close it with js.